# Here Maps route indication color

Tags: ios, here-api

I'd like to customize the color of the route indication (the one highlighted in this [route example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d46n1.jpg)). I'm using a map custom scheme and NMASchemeColorProperty like in [this example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/blob/master/map-customization-ios-swift/MapCustomizationApp/ViewController.swift) and I've tried various keys without success. Is this possible? What's the right key?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the SDK does not provide this feature. You cannot change the color of the navigation arrow.

Comment: @Tiw, the answer given is actually the correct answer. The feature being asked for (changing the color of the guidance arrow) is not yet provided in the HERE mobile SDK. Merlin1stHere is part of the HERE developer community.